# Django debugging with Emacs

Tags: python, django, debugging, emacs

I found a lot of info about how to debug simple Python programs with Emacs. But what if I want to debug a Django application?
I run the development server and I would like to somehow attach to the process from Emacs and then set breakpoints, etc. Similar to Visual Studio's "attach to process". How to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start pdb like this:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `pdb`

Then, start the Django development server:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Once you have the (Pdb) prompt, you need to do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/directory/containing/views.py')
```

Once you've done this, you should be able to set breakpoints normally. Just navigate to the line number you want, and

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd>

Comment: Also, if you are using pdb and Emacs, check out [PDBtrack](http://wiki.zope.org/klm/PDBTrack).

Answer (score 20):

This isn't emacs specific, but you can use the Python debugger by adding the following to a Django view function:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Now when you run the development server and view the page, your browser will appear to hang or load very slowly - switch over to your console, and you have access to the full debugger.  You can inspect AND modify state of your application via an interactive shell - check out the Python documentation for the debugger, or this link for some [Python debugging examples](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/09/01/debugger.html)

---

If all you need is logging, add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = '/tmp/mylog.log',
    filemode = 'w'
)
```

Now you can log messages to `/tmp/mylog.log` by adding the following to any view function:

```
import logging
logging.debug("Something happened")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I found last night that will do exactly what you want when the program crashes:

http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/

Once you install that you can run:

> python manage.py runserver_plus

and you will have an interactive `AJAX console` on your `Error` page.  (Obviously, be careful with the amount of access people have to this web server when running in that mode.)

GitHub: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

You can get Django Extensions by using pip or easy_install:

> $ pip install django-extensions or $ easy_install django-extensions

If you want to install it from source, grab the git repository from GitHub and run setup.py:

> $ git clone git://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git
>   $ cd django-extensions
>   $ python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

Because recent versions of Emacs python mode do support 'pdbtrack' functionality by default, all you need is just set up breakpoint in your code this way:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Also, you  have to start your Django application devserver from within Emacs shell:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell`

And then, in the shell, start the Django development server:

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

P.S. No need for specific pdb sessions or --noreload flag. Noreload would require you to manually restart your applications and so I do not find this useful for Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know anything about it, but putting "debugging Python with emacs" into Google gave me this page about [debugging twisted with emacs](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/debug-with-emacs.html), so it seems to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

About the general non-emacs-exclusive way, there is a very nice screencast out there you might be interested in: http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/31/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/

The emacs integration described above doesn't work for me yet. It doesn't really seem to connect to the running application.

Further I consider this blog post here very interesting: http://web.archive.org/web/20101230072606/http://panela.blog-city.com/python_and_emacs_5_pdb_and_emacs.htm

cu
Roman