# M-x breakpoints in python-mode in Emacs

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I have read in a several places (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283294/django-debugging-with-emacs)) that I can use `M-x space` to add/remove breakpoints in my python files when debugging with Emacs.

However, when I type `M-x space` once I have opened `pdb` on the file, Emacs prompts me with a large autocompletion list, as if I were to type any other `M-x command`

#### Q1:

How can I use `M-x space` to add or remove breakpoints once I have started a pdb session in Emacs?

#### Q2:

The top answer in the thread above says I should invoke the following two lines from pdb to use `M-x space` to add/remove breakpoints:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/directory/containing/views.py')
```

but what is `views.py`? Is that something specific to Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. `gud-break` is set to `C-x SPC` (`SPC` means space). I guess this is just a typo in the linked post.